# Can't Install New Games from the Xbox App or Microsoft Store error 0x800700b7

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store, uwp

I've been trying to install new games with the Xbox App in Windows 10 for over a week, and it always fails.

In the Xbox app the error reads "Something unexpected happened. Reporting this problem will help us understand it better. You can try waiting a bit and try again or restart your device. That might help.

Error code 0x800700b7"

When I look at the Microsoft Store for the same game the error is displayed as "Cannot create a file when that file already exists (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B).

I've tried it with different games, and free games, and even bought a game to see if that will be different. Nothing worked.

**One thing that is worth noting is that games previously installed on this PC can be reinstalled just fine.**

So far I tried;

- sfc /scannow
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- Ran CHKDSK on C:
- Performed a clean boot
- Ran the Windows apps troubleshooter
- Fully updated Windows 10
- Removed the Xbox app and reinstalled it
- Removed Gaming Services and reinstalled it
- Used GamingRepairTool.exe
- Created a new user account and tried on that one
- Logged in with the built-in administrator account and tried on that one
- Re-registered all the store apps
- Updated to Windows 11 (since I rolled back as it didn't help)
- Made an in-place repair install of Windows 10 (this increased my boot time for some reason)
  -Tried installing games to a different drive
- Removed my Microsoft Account and then added it back
- Tried installing the same games on another computer on mine with the same Microsoft account. They install fine on another PC.

Looking at the Event viewer I see this under Windows logs-> Application

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: AppxDeploymentFailureBlue
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 800700B7
P2: 22
P3: 3
P4: windows.stateExtension
P5: 10.0.19041.3930
P6: 5252
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10:
```

There are a bunch of .evtx files. The one I believe to be most relevant has some information.

I'll paste some of them. In this case the game I'm trying to install is The Elder Scrolls: Arena.

```
Setting Sync Enabled status, package family name BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_3275kfvn8vcwc, enabled false.

Creation of the secure system app data folder failed with error code : 0x800700B7.

An internal error occurred with error 0x800700B7. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

error 0x800700B7: While processing the request, the system failed to register the windows.stateExtension extension due to the following error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
error 0x800700B7: Cannot register the request because the following error was encountered during the registration of the windows.stateExtension extension: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

error 0x800703FA: While reverting the request, the system failed to de-register the windows.stateExtension extension due to the following error: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.

BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_1.4.0.0_x86__3275kfvn8vcwc : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_1.4.0.0_x86__3275kfvn8vcwc\S-1-5-21-2815226479-2402292899-535931247-1001-MergedResources-*.pri : No user-specific merged files found

BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_1.4.0.0_x86__3275kfvn8vcwc : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_1.4.0.0_x86__3275kfvn8vcwc\Resources.????????.pri : No shared merged files found

error 0x80073CF6: Cannot register the BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_3275kfvn8vcwc package due to the following error: Package could not be registered.

 The last successful state reached was SingletonRegisterAdd. Failure occurred before reaching the next state RegistrationChanged. hr: 0x80073CF6
The package deployment operation is now paused for package: BethesdaSoftworks.TheElderScrollsArena_1.4.0.0_x86__3275kfvn8vcwc
```

Do I have any way to fix this other than a clean install?

Comment: Is there a reason you are running Windows 20H1 (19041.3930)?

Comment: According to winver I'm running 'Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3930).'